# PHP script not work in cron

Tags: php, time, cron, statistics

I write a script to display the last registered users. The script checks if there is a new user, it adds it to the statistics table. If not, and it was 5 minutes after the last addition - that adds in  statistics table user from "fake users table".
If i run the script manually and update every minutes - it works. If via crontab - every minute, that does not work (if not add anew real user - that every minute of it adds fake  user). What could be the reason? I do not understand.

```
$last_add_time = mysql_query( get the time of adding the last new user);
$time_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //get the current time
$date_diff_array=real_date_diff($last_add_time,$time_now);// get the difference in minutes

if($date_diff>=5){

/*add fake user to the current time*/

}
```

Comment: Is it getting any errors?

Comment: Do you have execute permission for running the script as cli mode?

Comment: @Barmar no errors, but the condition is not working. It must add every 5 minute, but added every cron start.

Comment: @fortune i don't know. How it checked?

Comment: @fortune You don't need execute permission on a script if you run it like `php /path/to/script.php`.

Comment: Dear @Barmar you are right.

Comment: @T_E_M_A, please check, http://www.thecave.info/running-php-script-from-cron/ Not sure it will help you.